# Left align equation with multiple lines or long equations

Tags: math-mode, align

I have a long equation that needs to be separated into multiple lines to fit on my page.
I would like to align the first line of this equation to the LEFT of my page, and then the following line should be aligned to the = symbol of the first line.

For now I have the following

```
\begin{flalign}
    \begin{aligned}FC\ M-0\ Future\ MI\ (u) = CALCULATE([Quantity\ (u)],P2\_Profile\_Data \\ 
    [Cycle\_Distance] ="M-0", P2\_Profile\_Data[Profile]="MI", \\
    FinCalendar[Fin MonthOffset]>=1 \&\&
    FinCalendar[Fin MonthOffset]<=50
    )
    \end{aligned}
\end{flalign}
```

The code above doesn't align the first line to the left of the page, and the second line is not aligned to the = symbol of the first line.
[image: Screenshot of output]

Comment: please always show complete small documents not fragments. The image you show is set in text mode not math mode, so would not normally be produced by the fragment you show which is math mode. I suspect that there were other errors earlier in the document not shown and this output is just tex's error recovery.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish the \&\& and the unbalanced )?  Would \quad\text{and}\quad be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\scriptsize
    \begin{aligned}FC\ M-0\ Future\ MI\ (u) &= CALCULATE([Quantity\ (u)],P2\_Profile\_Data \\ 
    [Cycle\_Distance] &="M-0", P2\_Profile\_Data[Profile]="MI", \\
    FinCalendar[Fin MonthOffset]&\ge 1 \&\&
    FinCalendar[Fin MonthOffset]\le 50
    )
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But I am sure you could find better ways like placing the text inside `\text` commands and defining long words with "acronyms" so that the equation could fit in the text in `\normalsize`

Comment: Also, you should use quotes like \`\`  and `''`